# replicate a string with minor changes without a for loop

Tags: r

I have a couple of columns named "Lab1Date", "Lab3Date" "Lab7Date" etc and more column of the same pattern - the integer changes but not the rest of the string. I can generate a vector with such column names using a for loop easily, like

```
for (j in c(1,3,7,14,28)) {
    newcolorder <- c(newcolorder,paste0("Lab",j,"Date"))
}
```

But I was wondering whether there was a more elegant, idiomatic way in R, maybe using the likes of rep().

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop with `paste` i.e. `paste0('Lab', c(1,3,7, 14,28), 'Date')`

Comment: Oh. Thanks @akrun. I kind of feel silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` directly without a `for` loop as `paste` is vectorized.

```
paste0('Lab', c(1,3,7, 14,28), 'Date')
```